# WSO2 Identity Server and SSO for custom application

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We're currently evaluating the WSO2 Identity Server and I got a few questions about it:

1. Could the Identity Server be used as an SSO provider for custom applications deployed (just like CAS)? Is there a client API to access the server programatically to verify a ticket?
2. Is there a way to customize the login page of the Identity Server or substitute it with my own (and how)?
3. Is the Identity Server able to login users with digital certificates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is a good explanation [here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server) for your first question.
2. I believe you can download the source of Identity Server, modify the login page and then build. [WSO2 Identity Server documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS323/Building+WSO2+Identity+Server+from+source)

Comment: About 2. I'm asking about customizing the login page, not implementing it and building the entire server.

Comment: You do not have to compile the complete server. All you need to do is expand the org.wso2.carbon.ui-3.2.3.jar , or whatever version you are using, in the /opt/wso2/wso2is-3.2.3/repository/components/plugins/ directory,  and then go into the /org.wso2.carbon.ui-3.2.3.jar/web/admin directory and then modify the login.jsp directly.  Be sure to restart wso2 IS after expanding the jar, and remove the original jar, make sure that the expanded directory name is the same as the original jar

Comment: Thank you. Do you know something about login with x.509 certificates?

Comment: are you talking about installing a certificate in the browser and then using that to be identified during the login process?

Comment: I have not seen that done in wso2 .  I too will be interested to see if anybody has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

3- You can write a custom authenticator according to your requirement and plug it, dropping it at repository/components/dropins and editing repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml with the priority you give for this authentication mechanism.

You can refer existing authentictors' code, to get an idea at http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk01/components/authenticators/